# How to speed up searching alphabetized word list for leading wildcard matches

Tags: android, search, wildcard

I'm a word puzzle junky in my spare time, so I've spent a LOT of other spare time working on a helper program that allows wildcards in search patterns. It works great. On my Dell Laptop (i5, 8GB RAM) the search of a 140,000-word "dictionary" for wildcard matches for words has an almost imperceptible and definitely acceptable delay that occurs only if tens of thousands of words are returned. Java rules. So does its implementation of `regex` and `match()`.

I was hoping to port it to Android. I worked all day getting a more-or-less equivalent app to compile. No chance with given code architecture.

The problem is that leading wildcard characters can (must) be allowed. E.g., `???ENE` returns 15 matches--from `achENE` to `xylENE` and `*RAT` returns 22 matches--from `aristocRAT` through `zikuRAT--i.e., all 140,000 words must (?) be searched, which is going to take aaaaaaaaawhiiiiiiiiile on most (all?) Android devices. (Each took less than a second on my laptop.) (It takes my PC 3 seconds to return all 140,000 words and a little longer to eyeball them all.)

Since some word puzzles allow variable numbers of letters in words, disallowing leading wildcards cuts the heart out of the app for such puzzles. But if the search pattern had to start with a letter it would be easy enough to then do a binary search (or something quicker). (And it still might be unacceptably slow.)

Anyway, I was wondering if anybody might know some algorithm or can think of some approach that might be applied to speed up searches with leading wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the optimized version of what you are trying to do is widely known as the Unix/Linux utility "grep", which, if I remember correctly, uses the Boyer-Moore search algorithm.

Under the covers, Java's Pattern class uses Boyer-Moore. And it supports regex, so if you can write something to turn your wildcard search patterns into regular expressions, you can use Pattern.

There's an interesting Java implementation of grep at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/AnotherGrep.htm

It uses memory-mapped files. I'm guessing that you won't be able to fit your entire word list into memory, but you could split it up into a bunch of smaller files - the implementation above memory-maps one file at a time. You'd have to do some testing to find the optimal size of a file.

Comment: GreyBeardedGeek (from WhiteBeardedNerd): Thanks. I do use `regex` and `match()` after translating "Windows wildcards" (`*` and `?`) and my own `#` (like `?` but disallows using same letter twice or more) into equivalent `regex` syntax. The 140,000 words only occupy 1.4MB. I wonder about a list or document in RAM that large. `grep` program looks interesting.

Comment: Hmmmm... In `Netbeans` (so on my laptop, not Android) I put all 140k of the words into an `ArrayList`, which took the same 3 seconds reported earlier to return all 140k. But then subsequent requests for all 140k took about half the time. This may have promise.

Comment: On Android, it took a long time to load the 140,000 words but then it only took 15 seconds to give all 40 matches to `xy*` but it took 30 seconds to give all 32 matches to `*rat` but 15 seconds for `rat*`. I dunno where this is leading but maybe has promise.

Answer (score 0):

I just Googled and found having a second list reverse alphabetized might be a way to then have a leading wildcard become trailing, opening door to binary search for pattern start. Interesting. But `*a???ene*` is also a legal search pattern in the program. What then? (Yeah. How often would you need such a search.)

I just found this about Apache Lucene:

`Leading wildcards (e.g. *ook) are not supported by the QueryParser by default.` As of Lucene 2.1, they can be enabled by calling `QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true )`. Note that this can be an expensive operation: it requires scanning the list of tokens in the index in its entirety to look for those that match the pattern.

Comment: Once I get the list loaded into an `ArrayList`, using `Collections.binarySearch(...)` IMMEDIATELY finds matches for pattern that begins with letter and not wildcard.

But there's that problem of getting the 140,000 words into their `ArrayList` in a timely way (takes one minute on my phone). 

I wonder if the first time the app runs if making a file on the device would help. Haven't done files on a device. Assume I'm allowed.

Probably should do background thread to load the `ArrayList`, one way or other.